# Display PHP in Textarea

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to display a php variable in a text area but it just outputs what is in between the text area tags

Here's my code:

```
echo  "Allergens Contained "    .'<textarea rows="4"     name="Allergens_Contains">   <?php echo $contains; ?></textarea>';
```

In the text area on my webpage all I'm getting is: `<?php echo $contains; ?>`

Comment: you're already in PHP. `echo  "... <?php echo $contains; ?>...';` <= and the wrong quote. parse syntax error. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- still lost

Comment: you've been given an answer below. I've explained what's happening with your code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- ya aren't I concatenating the way he is in his third example

Comment: I wasn't "correcting" your code, I was "explaining" the syntax errors. Those are 2 different animals altogether ;-)

Comment: @Wo0dSiiE No you're not. Check your quotes.

Comment: you've been given an answer below from Jamie that shows you how to properly concatenate. Personally, I think it should be accepted and marked as solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should concatenate strings and variables via:

```
<?php
echo 'This is text ' . $php_variable . ' more text';
```

or

```
<?php
echo "This is text " . $php_variable . " more text";
```

or

```
<?php
echo "This is text $php_variable more text";
```

or

```
<?php
echo "This is text {$php_variable} more text";
```